# How do I add a subview which already has a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview, loadnibnamed

using the followings I can create a view and then load a nib into it:

```
CGRect newViewRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 335, 335, 400);
UIView *newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewRect];
newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheNewViewNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Here is the issue, when ever my xib file already contains a `UIView`, XCode logs only "lldb", but let's say if I delete the `UIView` in the xib file and add any other object, it shows perfectly fine.

But since I want to load the entire `UIView` with all everything inside it, I prefer to find a way to load the nib with a `UIView`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
 newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheNewViewNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This code reload your UIView variable "newView" by content of the nib file. Therefore  it is senselessly to create UIVew variable before this code scope.

If your view is composited. Just subclass UIView by your custom class, then add IBOutlet for each composite, then create xib with these composites, and linq them to IBoutlets. then just load xib as above well.

```
 newView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TheNewViewNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or to get access to composites without subclassing you just can use tag of subViews. in xib set tag for each view and then get access to them by [view viewWithTag:tag];